# Code Contracts and Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, code-contracts

Code contracts simply treats Tasks as it would with any other variable, instead of waiting for the result asynchronously. So, the following scenario will not work, and cause a Contracts exception since at the time the method returns, its an incomplete task, and the results wouldn't be set at that point in time. Is there any reasonable workaround for the following scenario?

```
public Task LoadAppModel()
{
    Contract.Ensures(app.User != null);
    Contract.Ensures(app.Security != null);
    Contract.Ensures(app.LocalSettings != null);

    return Task.WhenAll(
        store.GetUserAsync().ContinueWith(t => { app.User = t.Result; }),
        store.GetSecurityAsync().ContinueWith(t => { app.Security = t.Result; }),
        store.GetLocalSettingsAsync().ContinueWith(t => { app.LocalSettings = t.Result; }));
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. :) I'd rather not break the contract patterns.

Comment: what about using `Task.WaitAll()` instead of `WhenAll()`?

Comment: That breaks the asynchrony. The only way without breaking the asynchony seems to be splitting it up into numerous methods.

Comment: but the way you are describing it, it's not Async anyway?  the C# `Task` Class has existed before the async/await features, and don't always indicate that the methods using them are intended to be Async...

Comment: It will be asynchronous. The await happens outside of the snippet.

Comment: Situation has change after accepted answer. Adding this comment since google points to this thread as one of first sources about CodeContract and async. Check out my answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164213/code-contracts-and-asynchrony/40717675#40717675

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code contracts and `async` don't go together well, so you can't really use `Contract.Ensures`.

There is however a workaround. You can change your method from a `Task`-returning method to an `async` one (which would be cleaner anyway) and use `Contract.Assume` instead:

```
public async Task LoadAppModel()
{
    var userTask = store.GetUserAsync();
    var securityTask = store.GetSecurityAsync();
    var settingsTask = store.GetLocalSettingsAsync();
    await Task.WhenAll(userTask, securityTask,settingsTask);

    app.User = userTask.Result;
    app.Security = securityTask.Result;
    app.LocalSettings = settingsTask.Result;

    Contract.Assume(app.User != null);
    Contract.Assume(app.Security != null);
    Contract.Assume(app.LocalSettings != null);
}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick. Assumption, however changes the context rendering many of code contracts' derived features (documentation for example) useless. But I guess that's the best solution until code contracts supports async. Will mark this as answer, until async is implemented. Thanks :)